# jQuery cannot access certain parts of document

Tags: jquery

I created a jQuery document, however it cannot grab any element inside of only one type of element, `".media_container"`

The following code behaves in this manner:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    alert('alive');

    $('h1').css('background', 'pink');

    $('.media_container').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

1. `'alive'` is alerted, so I know that the file is being read correctly.
2. All headers **except** for headers inside `.media_container` turn pink.
3. Nothing happens when I hover over any `.media_containers`

I had the same problem with a different jQuery file on the same php page.
I tried .mouseover and .mouseenter with the same non-response.

**The Question**: With jQuery certain parts of the document are not accessible with $() and the inaccessible parts are within only one element type, .media_container - any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: `.media_containers` or `.media_container` ?? show ur html

Comment: if .media_container is inside an iframe jquery cannot access that.

Comment: See it's working! http://jsfiddle.net/WL6Pq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, and of course the reason and solution seems easy in hindsight. :)

**Reason: jQuery is really finnicky about order and timing**

- jQuery(document).ready() runs when all elements are written into the DOM.
- We used ajax to print '.media_container's onto the page

At the moment when the script is running, the page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload(){
        loadContent(); //which uses ajax to inject php into the html
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

      //empty

      <script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function(){
              $('.media_container').someFunction();
          });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[$(document).ready() happens before window.onload()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Therefore, even though the jQuery script is at the end of the `body`, it runs *before* the `loadContent()` script in the `head` which is triggered by `window.onload()`.

Further clarity, sequence of events:

```
1. Browser reads html/php document, top down.
2. Browser reads the script in the `head` and waits for `window.onload()`
3. Simultaneously, it loads the `html` elements into the DOM.
4. It reaches the end of the document and reads and loads a jQuery script and waits for `jQuery(document).ready()'
5. Since it's already basically done with loading the DOM, the jQuery script runs <i>before</i> the window.onload() script runs.
```

**Solution: `<img onload>`**

Even triggering the `loadContent()` on `document.ready()` instead of `window.onload()` doesn't work, because by the time it runs ajax and uses php to insert elements into the HTML, the jQuery script has already been run.

Therefore, I did two things to speed up the code:

1. I ran `loadContent()` on `document.ready()`
2. At the end of each ajax/php pull, I add a `media_container` with `visibility:hidden` and an `<img src='spaceholder.jpg' onload='attachFunctions()'>`, where attachFunctions() is defined in a script file run in the `head` and the problem is solved!

New Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              loadContent(); //which uses ajax to inject php into the html
            });
            attachFunctions(){
              $('.media_container').someFunction();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='media_container'></div>
        <div class='media_container'></div>
        <div class='media_container'></div>
        <div class='media_container' style='visibility:hidden'>
            <img src='spaceholder.jpg' onload='attachFunctions()'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```